# Refresh LinkedIn Access Token using Scribe

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api, access-token, scribe

I am using Scribe to access the LinkedIn API. I am saving the Access Token along with the Access Token Secret in the database and use them every time I call the API.

The Access Token is supposed to expire 60 days after it has been generated.

I would like to automatically refresh the access token before it expires. I couldn't find a way to do it programatically without the user intervention.

Comment: This is probably not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to be able to refresh the access token without the user's intervention. The system was designed this way in order to protect the user's data from being accessed indefinitely.

Linkedin wants to ensure that you cannot access the user's data unless they are actively using your application. To me, if a user doesn't visit your application within 60 days, it means that they aren't using it, and you should not be able to access that data.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Does this mean that if my application gets being used than, the access token will be renewed automatically? This wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: No. It means that you cannot refresh the access token if the user is not using your application. However, if you're using the Javascript API, this should be automatically done for you. If you're using server-side scripting, you will still have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @params={:"oauth_token"=>"XXXXXXXXXXX", 
 :oauth_token_secret=>"XXXXXXXXXXX", 
 :oauth_expires_in=>"5184000"}
```